# Apache2 mod_rewrite redirect all except one folder

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, python

I need to redirect the requests for my old website (www.old.com) to the new domain (www.new.com) but I would like to keep the old content available in a different folder (www.old.com/oldsite).
I've got the rule to redirect all requests but the folder exception doesn't seem to be working:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} www.old.com
RewriteRule ^/old_website/(.*) $1
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new.com/new_site_is_here.php
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add another RewriteCond that requires it to *not* be /oldsite.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oldsite.*
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing this the right way but it doesn't seem to work:

Comment: `RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} !www.old.com/www_old_com.*
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new.com/new_site_is_here.php

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.old.com
  RewriteRule ^/www_old_com/(.*) $1`